# Некорретное определение типа столбца с датой при импорте данных из mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Импортирую данные из mysql в базу MS SQL сервера через ODBC-источник.

Мастер импорта показывает на столбах типа date NOT NULL и date NULL как 23:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отчего такое происходит и как это можно поправить? Таблиц много, поэтому руками править каждую крайне утомительно.

Технические подробности:

- удалённый сервер centos6 с mysql v 5.1.73
- машина с Windows10 + сервер MS SQL 2012
- MYSQL ODBC драйвер 32bit v 5.3 Unicode

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49953875/5752652

Comment: таблицу то по итогу создает, что получается?

Comment: @teran разумеется, не создаёт, ругается на некорректный SQL-запрос создания таблицы.